# Does Spark benefit from `sortBy` in persistent table?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Spark v2.4 no Hive

Spark benefit from `bucketBy` in a way that it knows the DataFrame has the correct partitioning. What about `sortBy`?

```
spark.range(100, numPartitions=1).write.bucketBy(3, 'id').sortBy('id').saveAsTable('df')

# No need to `repartition`.
spark.table('df').repartition(3, 'id').explain()
# == Physical Plan ==
# *(1) FileScan parquet default.df2[id#33620L] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[df], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<id:bigint>, # SelectedBucketsCount: 3 out of 3

# Still need to `sortWithinPartitions`.
spark.table('df').sortWithinPartitions('id').explain()
# == Physical Plan ==
# *(1) Sort [id#33620L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
# +- *(1) FileScan parquet default.df2[id#33620L] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[df], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<id:bigint>, SelectedBucketsCount: 3 out of 3
```

So additional `repartition` is omitted. However, `sortWithinPartitions` is not. Is `sortBy` useful? Can we use `sortBy` to speed up table joining at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer** : There is no benefits from `sortBy` in persistent tables (at the moment at least).

**Longer answer** :

Spark and Hive do not implement the same *semantics* or the *operational* specifications when it comes to *bucketing* support, although Spark can save bucketed DataFrame into a Hive table.

*First*, the units of bucketing are different between both frameworks:  single bucket file (hive) vs. collection of files per bucket (spark).

*Second*,

In **Hive**, each bucket is sorted globally which can optimize queries reading data.

In **Spark** and till this issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19256
gets (hopefully) resolved, each file is individually sorted but the bucket as a whole is not globally sorted.

Thus, *since sorting is not global*, there is **no benefits** form `sortBy`.

I hope this answers your question.